# Replace derivatives using vector notation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

I seek to replace derivatives like `D[u[x, y], x, x]` which are evaluated as $u^{(2,0)}[x,y]$ by variables with names like `uxx`. Derivatives that I work with are denoted by their "order-vector", for example `{2,0}` is the vector for this particular derivative and `{1,1}` is for `uxy`. I have a list of different derivative vectors and I want to create rule for replacement which is comprised of elements like $u^{(2,0)}[x,y]\rightarrow uxx$. But for that, I need to transform {2,0} into (2,0) which mathematica doesn't want to do:

```
dsT={1,0,0,0};
ToExpression[StringReplace[ToString[dsT], {"}" -> ")", "{" -> "("}]]
```

This returns an error though without "ToExpression" the output is exaxtly what I need "(1, 0, 0, 0)". How can I do this conversion for any length of derivative vector?

Comment: Your `ToExpression` approach won't work because `(1, 0, 0, 0)` is not a valid Mathematica expression (try entering it directly and see). Instead, note that $u^{(2,0)}[x,y]$ is actually represented internally as `Derivative[2, 0][u][x, y]`, as you can find out by evaluating `FullForm` on such an expression. So you should be replacing expressions involving `Derivative[2, 0]`, not involving `(2, 0)`.

Comment: @Rahul but neither `2,0` is a valid mathematica expression. How can I put it into Derivative[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be:

```
dsT = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0};
vars = Table[ToExpression["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, Length[dsT]}];

\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"Sequence", "@@", "dsT"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[Sequence @@ vars]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
derivativeToSymbol[expr_] /; Nest[Head, expr, 3] === Derivative := Block[{args, tmp},
          args = List @@ expr; tmp = Head[expr];
          Symbol[(ToString @@ tmp) <> 
                 MapThread[ConstantArray, {ToString /@ args, List @@ Head[tmp]}]]]
```

Examples:

```
derivativeToSymbol[D[u[x, y], x, x]]
   uxx

derivativeToSymbol[D[u[x, y, z], {x, 3}, z]]
   uxxxz
```

Comment: Can I adopt that to unknown number of variables? Like if I know their number beforehand how to write function `u` as `u[t1,t2,t3...tn]` automatically with just the number `n`?

Comment: Nope. But you should have included that requirement in your question if you really need it.

Comment: There is really no way to declare list of arguments for a function? I can generate this "code" by very simple string manipulatios.